# onclick function in angularjs : nothing happens

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm little confused with onclick function , with angularjs...

in my controller, i put this :

```
$('#mapReload').click(function () {
    alert('lol');
});
```

nothing work... jquery is correctly added, where i'm wrong ?

Comment: Why do you need jQuery event binding? Whats wrong with `ngClick`?

Comment: Are you even using angular? Can you update with your controller and template code?

Comment: try "$window.alert('lol');"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML use ng-click for button click:

```
<button ng-click="reloadMap()">Map Reload</button>
```

And in your angularJS controller, write click handler:

```
$scope.reloadMap = function() {
    alert('lol');
};
```

Comment: There are two problems with your jsfiddle: 1). ng-controller directive should be given to parent container element. Yours is incorrect. 2). ng-app directive is needed for angular app to work, which i have added in [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshcp/ux8Vw/2/) in fiddle options=>body tag.

Comment: why angularjs is needed in <head> ? i learn to put my JS in last, in <body>

Comment: It is only for jsFiddle to work properly. In your server, you can add your angularjs code file at the end of the page and this code will work. You can test jsFiddle with `No wrap - in <body>` and it will place js code just before `</body>` and that also will work.

Comment: I hope this helped you. Let us know. Thanks.